# JSON to XML Transformation using XSLT 3.0

Tags: java, xml, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am using Java 1.8, Saxon-HE version 9.9.1-4 version and xslt3.0 to tranform the JSON to XML.

**Input JSON**

```
{
    "analystId": "Test",
    "jobId": "",
    "profileData": {
        "allAuthorCoverage": false,
        "assetClasses": [
            {
                "code": "Test1"
            }
        ]
        
    }   
}
```

**XSLT3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" /> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="jsonText"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template name="init">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($jsonText)"/> 
  </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="*[@key]" >
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML Generated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <analystId xmlns="">Test</analystId>
   <jobId xmlns=""/>
   <profileData xmlns="">
      <allAuthorCoverage>false</allAuthorCoverage>
      <assetClasses>
         <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
            <code xmlns="">Test1</code>
         </map>
      </assetClasses>
   </profileData>
</map>
```

**Output XML Expected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<analystId>Test</analystId>
<jobId />
<profileData>
    <allAuthorCoverage>false</allAuthorCoverage>
    <assetClasses>
        <code>Test1</code>
    </assetClasses>
</profileData>
```

We can still see `<map>` element and xmlns attribute in the generated output and my requirement is to remove the same.

How can I remove the Map element from the generated output and xmlns attribute as well?

Also in case I expand my JSON structure with new attributes these map element and xmlns attribute should not be added back again.

Comment: You will need to edit your question and show us the XML you want to output.

Comment: For a start, if you don't want to copy nodes from the input I would simply remove the `xsl:template match="@* | node()"` from the code that you have shown.

Comment: [~Martin] Apologies for not adding the expected output. I have added the expected output for the reference

Comment: Then I think my answer covers that, you simply have put a template with the identity transformation in your code you should rather omit.

Comment: Your expected output is not an XML file, but can be included as a fragment. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: @Christian I agree with you. But even I dont have complete JSON with me as it is coming from the upstream system. They are still working on the same so I just took whatever I have.Within next one or two days I am hoping to get more details

Comment: @JineshParikh Thank you for sharing this topic, I'm working on a similar code, could you please share with me  a java code snippet, on how are you passing the jsonText parameter to the XSL stylesheet ? or any code sample that will help on understanding the conversion flow. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the identity template you have used and instead omit it only your template to transform elements with a `key` attribute into elements of the name of the `key` value and any text nodes will create output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="jsonText" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[{
    "analystId": "Test",
    "jobId": "",
    "profileData": {
        "allAuthorCoverage": false,
        "assetClasses": [
            {
                "code": "Test1"
            }
        ]

    }   
}]]></xsl:param>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($jsonText)"/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@key]" >
        <xsl:element name="{@key}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It worked . I have one more simple question. If I take the json-to-xml($jsonText) in a variable in xslt. How can I access the individual elements from that variable which has the whole XML.

Comment: You are working with XSLT 3 where the selection language to access nodes in general or of course also elements in an XML document (it does not matter whether it is created from JSON) is XPath 3 so you select elements with any XPath 3 expression you need. The format of the XML is described in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json-to-xml-mapping, for your sample JSON you can see it by outputting `<xsl:sequence select="json-to-xml($jsonText)"/>`.

Comment: The elements are in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions` so declare with e.g. `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` and select e.g. `//fn:map[@key = 'profileData']`.

Comment: Thanks for Help @Martin honnen I have few other questions but let me try to resolve it and if not I will raise it over here